# Filter a sheet to keep rows only when they have a value in one column OR another column

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, conditional-operator

I've got an array of 5 rows, 5 columns (as an example, my spreadsheet has 500 rows). I would like // to set a filter on that sheet to keep only rows which column 4 or clumn 5 equal to a value.

I don't have any issue to set a filter to one column.

I'm completly lost to set a filter on two columns with an OR condition

I would appreciate any help'

Answer (score 0):

It's always more easy for helpers if you can provide some data set. But besides that, a short answer to your question is: use `|`.
Example data set:

```
specie <- c(rep("A" , 3) , rep("B" , 3) , rep("C" , 3) , rep("D" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c(1, 2, 3) , 4)
value <- rep(c(2, 4, 5) , 4)
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
data
   specie condition value
1       A         1     2
2       A         2     4
3       A         3     5
4       B         1     2
5       B         2     4
6       B         3     5
7       C         1     2
8       C         2     4
9       C         3     5
10      D         1     2
11      D         2     4
12      D         3     5
```

So now, if you want to only keep columns with value 2, you can do it as follows:

```
filter(data, condition == 2 | value == 2)
  specie condition value
1      A         1     2
2      A         2     4
3      B         1     2
4      B         2     4
5      C         1     2
6      C         2     4
7      D         1     2
8      D         2     4
```

Comment: function filterRows() {
  var i = 0
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //get active spreadsheet
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 1"); //get active sheet
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const v = sh.getRange("D1").getValue();//get the value that I want to filter
  let filter = sh.getFilter();
  console.log(v);// ok it's the correct value
  console.log(vs);// ok it's the correct array
  //console.log(vs[5][3]); //not working, get the message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '3')""

Comment: and then trying to filter

Comment: const formula = (D3 == "Eric" || E3 = "Eric");//trying to get a result with OR operator
  const newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
 .whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)
 .build(); 
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(4, newCriteria); // trying to filter
}

Comment: nom prenom adresse ecole1 ecole2
Dupond Sébastien 31 rue du docteur George Jean
Durand Sébastien 19 rue du paradis Eric Jean
Dumichel Pierre 17 av dutilleul George Jean
Dupond Sébastien 31 rue du docteur Paul Eric

Comment: my set of data, I'm sorry I'm unable to keep it in the good format

Answer (score 0):

**Filter Data**

```
function filterData(v=10) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sr = 2;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => r[3] == v || r[4] == v);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}
```

Data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 6 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 7 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 8 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 9 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 10 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 11 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |

Results:

```
Execution log
10:52:43 AM Notice  Execution started
10:52:44 AM Info    [[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]]
10:52:45 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Hello Cooper,

Thanks for your answer, it's exactly the results that I want to get. It remains one thing to do. I would like to apply this filter to my data in my sheet (not seeing the results in the console). I've tried that but it's not working at all, no filter,

Comment: function filterData2(v="Eric") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 2;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  
  let filter = sh.getFilter();
  const formula = filter(r => r[3] == v || r[4] == v);

  const newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
 .whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)
 .build(); 
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(4, newCriteria);

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
 }

Comment: How did you execute the function and I'm sorry but I never use the spreadsheet filters.  I think they are PITA and they are not as flexible.

Comment: you have the module (a interpretor) which a side sheet where your code is written. You could execute from here or otherwise write your function in your Googlesheet and press enter